# Documentation for GrapeCity ActiveReports web-designer.js

Tags: web, documentation, designer, activereports, grapecity

Where can one find the documentation for Active Reports 15.1.1.0 web-designer.js for a custom implementation of their Web Designer?

Answer (score 0):

At this link you can find the documentation for ActiveReports 15 WebDesigner: https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsnet/docs/v15/online/pure-js-integration-wd.html

Comment: Thank you, however we have already gone through your online help for AR 13, 14, and 15 trying to understand how we can limit the functionality of your web designer.

For instance, we need to limit the options for DataSources to only JSON, thereby hiding all the other options. Is that possible? Is there a designerOption for this? 

That is just one of the many modifications we need to make to the web designer in order for it to be useful to our customers.